# Chinese language not being reflected in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, localization, windows-10, chinese-locale

In my settings I have following 3 languages, and **Chinese Simplified** is at the top because I wanted to test it for my UWP app, as my app has 3 folders for my **Resource** file i.e **en** , **es** and **zh** . zh represents chinese simplified.

[image: languages]

When I launch my uwp app it is supposed to show **Chinese** text, but it shows **Spanish** instead, as spanish is the second option in the priority list of languages.When spanish is on top it still shows spanish, and when English is on top then it shows english, so the problem is only with Chinese language here.

First I thought there is some problem with my localization, but that is not the case because even the built-in tooltip on `NavigationView` toggle button is showing spanish instead of Chinese, so the uwp app as a whole is not picking up Chinese language.

Comment: What is your chinese resource file name?

Comment: resource file name is same as english and spanish "Resources.resw" folder name is "zh" but I dnt think that is the problem in this case bcz the built in tooltip and settings label text on NavigationView are not affected by these resource files.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of you `Package.appxmanifest` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long investigation, I think I have found the reason. If you check the documentation for [`CultureInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can find this:

> A neutral culture is specified by only the two-letter lowercase
>   language code. For example, "fr" specifies the neutral culture for
>   French, and "de" specifies the neutral culture for German.
>
> There are two culture names that contradict this rule. The cultures
>   Chinese (Simplified), named zh-Hans, and Chinese (Traditional), named
>   zh-Hant, are neutral cultures. The culture names represent the current
>   standard and should be used unless you have a reason for using the
>   older names "zh-CHS" and "zh-CHT".

So using just `zh` as the culture tag is not enough and you need to use either `zh-Hans` for simplified or `zh-Hant` for traditional Chinese. Renaming the folder to one of these (depending on your localization) should do the trick.